# All of my lines in my canvas change color when i change for one line

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have fun making lines that are drawn automatically, and I would like it to come back to the middle and change color when it comes out of the canvas size. Everything is done, it comes back well in the middle, and changes color well. But a little problem! All my lines that were already drawn before change to the same color.... I've been looking for an hour without a solution ^^

Can you help me?

Here are the parts of my code that I think are the most important for this problem :

There is my line !

```
function Line(x0, y0, x1, y1, color) {
              this.x0 = x0;
              this.y0 = y0;
              this.x1 = x1;
              this.y1 = y1;
              this.color = color;
              this.draw = function() {
                ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
                ctx.moveTo(this.x0, this.y0,)
                ctx.lineTo(this.x1, this.y1);
                ctx.stroke();
              }
            }
```

There is my function to create line !

```
var x = cx;
var y = cy;
var color = randomColor();
var lines = [];

function loop() {
    var newx = randomPoint(x, 100);
    var newy = randomPoint(y, 100);
    var line = new Line(x, y, newx, newy, color);
    x = newx;
    y = newy;

    lines.push(line);

    if(x > canvas.width || y > canvas.height || x < 0 || y < 0) {
        x = cx;
        y = cy;
        color = randomColor();
    }

    lines[0].draw();
    lines = [];

    time = setTimeout(loop, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `ctx.beginPath()` at the top of your `draw` function:

```js
class Line {
  constructor(x0, y0, x1, y1, color) {
    this.x0 = x0;
    this.y0 = y0;
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(this.x0, this.y0);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x1, this.y1);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
} 

function randomColor() {
  return ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'magenta'][Math.random() * 6 | 0];
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const maxWidth = window.innerWidth;
const maxHeight = window.innerHeight;
const cx = maxWidth / 2 | 0;
const cy = maxHeight / 2 | 0;

canvas.width = maxWidth;
canvas.height = maxHeight;

let counter = 0;
let x0 = cx;
let y0 = cy;
let color = randomColor();

function drawLine() {
    const x1 = x0 + Math.random() * 200 - 100;
    const y1 = y0 + Math.random() * 200 - 100;
    
    new Line(x0, y0, x1, y1, color).draw(ctx);
    
    x0 = x1;
    y0 = y1;

    if (x0 < 0 || y0 < 0 || x0 > maxWidth || y0 > maxHeight) {
        x0 = cx;
        y0 = cy;
        color = randomColor();
    }
    
    if (++counter > 500) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
}

const intervalID = setInterval(drawLine, 100);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

However, note that with this approach the joints between the different line segments don't look continuous (the sharper the join, the more obvious this is), so you might prefer to create a new path only when you change color and go back to the center:

```js
const COLORS = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'magenta'];
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const maxWidth = window.innerWidth;
const maxHeight = window.innerHeight;
const cx = maxWidth / 2 | 0;
const cy = maxHeight / 2 | 0;

canvas.width = maxWidth;
canvas.height = maxHeight;
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

let counter = -1;
let currentColor = -1;
let x = -1;
let y = -1;

function drawLines() {
  if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > maxWidth || y > maxHeight) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = COLORS[currentColor = (currentColor + 1) % COLORS.length];
    ctx.moveTo(x = cx, y = cy);
  }

  x += Math.random() * 200 - 100;
  y += Math.random() * 200 - 100;

  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();

  if (++counter === 500) {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
}

const intervalID = setInterval(drawLines, 100);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Actually, I got the problem of joints ! That's don't look continuous ! Even with the second code, i had the path only when i restart, but thats look like if i had path when i creat a new segment !
Do you have any idea to fix it ? To look continuous ?

Comment: I found the problem, the problem is moveTo ! But i need to use it ! And i don't know how can I use it only once at the beginnig of every color..

Comment: If I understood you correctly, if what you want is that once the line goes outside the canvas it comes back to the centre (drawing a line) before switching to a different color and starting again, you need to add `ctx.lineTo(cx, cy)` and `ctx.stroke()` before the `ctx.beginPath()`, in both examples.